# How to join two table in SQL like this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

There are two tables that are master and detail table. I show them in the bellow picture. First is master and the other one is detail table. Master table stores limit amounts for rate and detail table stores rate and day for rate. I use tables for calculating ratio. For example ratio of amount between 0.00 and 1000.00 for 1 day is 1.

[image]

I want to join them for creating a result table that shows ratio list in the following format:

[image]

Columns names are hard-code, please ignore them.

How to write SQL join script?

I use MSSQL Server 2014.

Comment: "How to write SQL join script?" - Press buttons.

Comment: How are the two tables related to each other? And I don't get the count of what?

Comment: seems relation like: `ID` of master table with 'Repo_Rate_Master_ID` of child table

Comment: @NagendraNigade, just what I though, but it would be great if such info was included in the question. (Hint!)

Comment: Yes...Totally Agree !

Comment: I forgot to show their relationship. 'Repo_Rate_Master_ID` of child table is ID of master table. Sory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but it looks like you want to do a pivot transformation. Try this:

```
select 
    number_of_day, [0-1000], [1000-5000], [5000-15000] 
from 
(
    select number_of_day, concat(min_amount,'-', max_amount) range, rate 
    from master join detail on detail.repo_rate_master_id = master.id
) x 
pivot 
(
    max(rate) for range in ([0-1000], [1000-5000], [5000-15000])
) p
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6fcd/1)

Comment: You are too fast for me, I created same code, and just to paste it, I see someone already paste it :) But I must give you a upvote

Comment: Thank you for your interest. But all values are null for [0-1000], [1000-5000], [5000-15000] columns. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know. Did you look at the example SQL fiddle? Is it different from the data you test on?

Comment: It is run, thank you so much for your help. There is a conversation problem in my data.